# Laravel error while trying to migrate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to add another column to my database table users. I made a new migration named `Modify_users_table`which has the code to add the column. There is nothing wrong with the source code because I used it before, but it gives me an error that something is wrong with the table roles? How can I solve this? Here is the error and the code that is related to the error
[image]

Here is the migration `Roles`:

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('role_name')->length(55)->unique();
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: It means that your roles table already exists, but it's not present in the `migrations` table. Find out why that happened and fix it with a rollback or reset. (this will remove all existing data in the tables though)

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, it is much better to include errors as text instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

if that also fails just go in and drop all the tables which you may have to do as it seems your migration table is messed up or your roles table when you ran a previous rollback did not drop the table.

or you can use `migrate:reset` command will roll back all of your application's migrations:

```
php artisan migrate:reset
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got a number of problems.  Your main problem is that you aren't adding a column to a table.  Your script is instead trying to create a new table, as seen in this line:

```
Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
```

You said you are trying to add a column to the users table, but you aren't even working with the user's table: you are instead creating a table called `roles` which already exists.  The simplest solution is to do what Dhaval suggests: ditch the migration you are added, update the migration that creates the user tables, nuke and start over.

The "right" answer is to create a new migration and put in the instructions to add the column to the users table as well as instructions on removing it.  Then you can just do a simple migration instead of nuking your database.  That would look something like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function ( Blueprint $table ) {
        $table->string('last_name')->after( 'first_name' )->default( '' );
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table( 'users', function ( Blueprint $table ) {
        $table->dropColumn( ['last_name'] );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I tried something like this and it works perfect for me. My Laravel version is 5.5.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::connection('mysql2')->create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');             
        $table->string('name');                      
        $table->string('image');            
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::connection('mysql2')->dropIfExists('images');
}
```

I had to connections in my project one is **mysql** and other is **mysql2** becuase my project is for database with multiple connections.

So my solution is that to try specifying the connection to your database in the function.

By default connection is **mysql** if you havent specifed it in the function, Example is given below. Hope this helps!

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');                
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email',60)->unique();
            $table->string('password');                
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
```

And so when you migrate using php artisan it doesn't show errors,

Answer (score -1):

remove the table from the database ( I did it manually the first time I had this issue)

and make this change in the create_users_table migration as such

```
$table->string('email', 60)->unique();
```

and this worked for me..

Hope this helps you as well